# Query Ajuda SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
select T.n_acid,T.marca

from (select n_acid, veic_seguro, marca

from marca_acid as ma, veiculo as v

where ma.veic_seguro = v.n_veic) as T

group by T.n_acid, T.marca;
```

Esta query devolve a tabela que aparece na foto. Preciso que a query devolva a marca de carro que aparece em todos os os 8 n_acid que existem , ou seja, preciso que devolva "Mercedes-benz"

Alguma ideia?

Comment: use o filtro "like"

Comment: Mas eu não quero que a query tenha "Mercedes", quero que ele chegue lá e devolva isso

Comment: com o like, você pode fazer uma alteração dinâmica na query utilizando php por exemplo, não há como você retornar algo específico sem dar um filtro para tal

Comment: a partir da query acima , preciso de contar quantas vezes aparece cada marca de carro e ver se isso é igual à contagem de linhas da tabela acidente ( a tabela acidente tem uma coluna n_acid)

Comment: Esclarece aí para nós. Neste caso que mostrou para nós  você precisa retornar "Mercedes-benz", OK. Mas qual critério ? Você citou o seguinte *Preciso que a query devolva a marca de carro que aparece em todos os os 8 n_acid que existem* O que você tentou dizer com isso ? Pois o Audi também tem um `n_acid` 8. Resumindo, explique melhor o por que o seu retorno deveria ser este.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
SELECT n_acid, marca, COUNT(*)
FROM marca_acid as ma INNER JOIN veiculo as v ON (ma.veic_seguro = v.n_veic)
GROUP BY n_acid, marca;
```

O ideal seria você qualificar a tabela de cada campo, o que não dá para adivinhar pelo texto de sua pergunta.